# How to catch only the last line of another command executed inside batch script with CALL

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have to write a simple batch script for windows that have to "launch" another script and return only the last line of the output of the launched program.

I need this to catch the "status" of the launched command, that it's printing something like: "End programm with code 0" after many ( and not known number of other line )

What I need is to catch only the last line of myprogram.cmd inside my catch.cmd

I'll try to use CALL inside my catch.cmd script to run myprogram.cmd, but I don't know how to manipulate and get back the last output line.

If I use only `CALL myprogram.cmd` I'll get all the output inside my catch.cmd, I'll try with `CALL myprogram.cmd >NULL` to hide all the output inside my catch.cmd, but how to get the last line of the myprogram.cmd?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I've created two files.

called.bat:

```
@echo off
dir c:\
```

caller.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('call called.bat') do set lastLine=%%f
echo %lastLine%
```

Running caller.bat will execute called.bat "in silence" and save the last line in the variable `%lastLine%`.

So in your case the anser will be this line:

```
...
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('call myprogram.cmd') do set lastLine=%%f
if "%lastLine%"=="End programm with code 0" (
    ::DO SOMETHING
)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's works perfect, I made some change to better organize the workflow.
Just a little "consideration", I don't know if it was a mistake or it's could depend by environment used, for the "caller.bat" I have used:
`for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('called.bat') do (
    set lastLine=%%f
)
`
instead the "plain": `do set lastLine=%%f`

Comment: Actually, skipping the parenthesis should make no difference.